# Why useState is not accepting input received from the GET request?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to get an object from the server in the form `{Name: true, Place: false, Animal: true, Thing: true}` save this data into `categoryDetail` then extract it using `categoryDetail.Name` and then pass it to the `useState`. But somehow `useState` is not accepting this data.

Here is the code:

```
const [categoryDetail, setCategoryDetail] = useState({});
    
useEffect(() => {
  axios.get('http://localhost:8080/feeds/category')
  .then(response => {
               
    if (JSON.stringify(categoryDetail) 
      !== JSON.stringify(response.data.category)) {
      setCategoryDetail(response.data.category);
    }
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  })
})

console.log(categoryDetail.Name);  //  this gives ``true``

const [name, setName] = useState(categoryDetail.Name);
const [place, setPlace] = useState(categoryDetail.Place);
const [animal, setAnimal] = useState(categoryDetail.Animal);
const [thing, setThing] = useState(categoryDetail.Thing);

console.log(name);  // but here i am getting ``undefined``
```

(I have commented on the value I am getting)

Please guide me on why is this happening and what to do so that `useState` accepts the data receive by the server.Also let me know if more information is required.

Comment: That's because the setState is asynchronous , your console log get printed before useState(categoryDetail.Name) is finishde

Comment: @FaizalHussain Could you please explain a bit more

Comment: means the code wont be executed line by line ,  the compiler will  move to the next line before finishing useState(categoryDetail.Name);

Answer (score 1):

Try make your code like this

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const App = () => {
    const [categoryDetail, setCategoryDetail] = useState({});
    const [name, setName] = useState('');
    // const [place, setPlace] = useState('');
    // const [animal, setAnimal] = useState('');
    // const [thing, setThing] = useState('');

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchCategories = async () => {
            await axios
                .get('https://mocki.io/v1/5a61740b-d272-4943-abe3-908628510020')
                .then((response) => {
                    setCategoryDetail(response.data.categories[0]);
                    setName(response.data.categories[0].categoryName);
                });
        };
        fetchCategories();
    }, []);

    // https://mocki.io/v1/5a61740b-d272-4943-abe3-908628510020
    return (
        <>
            <p>{name}</p>
            <p>{JSON.stringify(categoryDetail)}</p>
        </>
    );
};

export default App;
```

And as you see , I am doing call to setName after fetchCategories() inside of async/await call , put other state setters there

Comment: This does not work  as  setName(categoryDetail.categoryName); will execute before the api gets finishde

Comment: Yep it will execute before the end of api call , are you sure that in the jsx I won't see any result ? @FaizalHussain – 
Hakob Sargsyan

Comment: @FaizalHussain yes you are right , I have move setName(categoryDetail.categoryName); to the then callback

Answer (score 0):

You set default value `categoryDetail.Name` for `useState` which will be never modified in renderings (I'm doubting that it's possibly undefined or an error if `categoryDetail` data is not there)

If you want to get `name` data from `categoryDetail`. You can set state after receiving response from `useEffect`

```
const [name, setName] = useState(''); //to be safe, set it empty
useEffect(()=>{
        axios.get('http://localhost:8080/feeds/category')
            .then(response=>{
               
                if (JSON.stringify(categoryDetail) !== JSON.stringify(response.data.category)) {
                    setName(response.data.category.name); //set `name` into the state
                    setCategoryDetail(response.data.category);
                }
                
            })
            .catch(err=>{
                console.log(err);
            })
    })
```

From your logic, seemingly you're trying to access one by one field from `categoryDetail` state which is not preferable

If you want to get `name`, you just simply get it from `categoryDetail.Name` which is already set in the state

```
const[categoryDetail, setCategoryDetail]=useState({});
    
    useEffect(()=>{
        axios.get('http://localhost:8080/feeds/category')
            .then(response=>{
               
                if (JSON.stringify(categoryDetail) !== JSON.stringify(response.data.category)) {
                    
                    setCategoryDetail(response.data.category);
                }
                
            })
            .catch(err=>{
                console.log(err);
            })
    })

    //make sure your categoryDetail is not undefined
    if(categoryDetail) {
       console.log(categoryDetail.Name);
    }
```